# How to change background color in react materialUI card

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Hi i want to change background color of card in  react materialUI card project.
see the attached picture what i am expecting.

Screenshot:

[image]

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-snmhbw

Comment: I do not see any styles in your CSS file

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add an inline style block to your div element that holds the text. So something like this `style={{backgroundColor: "red"}}`

Comment: this is working for me but how can i make with css class name instead of inline style

Comment: You can create a css file and import it at the top inside your component file. Should look something like  import '../mycss.css' ;  . Once you import it you can use ```className="yourclass" ``` and then define yourclass inside the css file you created. I used ```className``` instead of  ```class``` because jsx cannot understand the  ```class``` keyword

Answer (score 6):

The nicer way is to set a global theme as described in the [MUI documentation](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/palette) and change the `theme.palette.background.paper` key to the hex value of your desired background color as discussed in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/15066):

1. Use:

```
    const theme = createTheme({
        palette: {
          background: {
            paper: '#EFF7FF', // your color
          },
        },
      });
```

2. Wrap your app in a `<ThemeProvider theme={theme}>`.
3. Just use your `<Card>` like normal and the color will be changed.

Comment: Nice to use the theme, but this setting also changes the background color for dropdowns.

Comment: Do you know why so many ui libraries are like this? I often want to dynamically change the color of a lot of ui elements and I always have to create and wrap each one in a theme instead of simply setting a color property, even though they have other elements (usually tags) that do support this kind of theming by setting a color property

Comment: @Jeffmagma I think they do it to promote reusability of all your colors. The nice thing about this is that you only have to change it in one place and then it will change in a lot of fitting places. This makes it simpler to e.g. implement dark mode. However, I also feel your concerns on making simple changes harder. I guess for tags it is a different story because you more often change their colors very dynamically.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to change the background color of the cards,

```
<Card style={{backgroundColor: "red"}}></Card>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no code in your stackblitz. Anyways.
Just do.

```
<Card className={classes.card}>
  <CardContent style={{backgroundColor: "red"}}>
    Your card content..
  </CardContent>

</Card>
```

Answer (score 1):

To have a good effect in both light and dark theme, something like this may work well:

```
const CardWithVariant = ({ variant }) => { // the variant can be "primary", "secondary", ...
  return (
    <Card
      sx={{
        backgroundColor: `${variant}.main`,
        color: `${variant}.contrastText`,
      }}
    >
      <CardContent>
        <Typography variant="h6">Hello World!</Typography>
        <Typography>How are you?</Typography>
      </CardContent>
    </Card>
  );
};
```

These are the links to the StackBlitz for your reference:

application: https://stackblitz-starters-gvwqsq.stackblitz.io

source code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-gvwqsq?file=src%2FApp.tsx

[image]
[image]